# Adding a trigger in Quartz scheduler for future use

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Quartz API provide a way in which i can create a Job and add it to scheduler for future use by doing something like

```
SchdularFactory.getSchedulerInstance().addJob(jobDetail, false);
```

This provides me the flexibility to create jobs store them with the scheduler and use them in later stage.
i am wondering is there any way i can create triggers and add them to scheduler to be used in future.

Not sure if this is valid requirement but if its not possible than all i have to do is to associate the Trigger with any given/existing Job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Quartz there is a one-to-many relationship between jobs and triggers, which is understandable: one job can be run by several different triggers but one trigger can only run a single job. If you need to run several jobs, create one composite job that runs these jobs manually.

Back to your question. Creating a job without associated triggers is a valid use-case: you have a piece of logic and later you will attach one or more triggers to execute it at different points in time.

The opposite situation is weird - you want to create a trigger that will run something at a given time, but you don't know yet what. I can't imagine use-case for that.

Note that you can create a trigger for future use (with next fire time far in the future), but it must have a job attached.

Finally, check out [**How-To: Storing a Job for Later Use**](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/cookbook/StoreJob) in the official documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.Can you please explain what you mean by "create one composite job that runs these jobs manually"?

Comment: @user702325: this does not really concern your question, it was just off-topic. I meant that Quartz is not capable of running multiple jobs by a single trigger so if you really need to do this (you need to run `Job1` and `Job2` by the same trigger), you must create `CompositeJob` that simply calls `Job1.execute()` and `Job2.eecute()`.